Unable to Capture Lambda Function Response in AWS Step Functions
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to capture the response from a Lambda function in an AWS Step Functions state machine. Despite various attempts, I'm unable to retrieve the response body correctly. Here's an outline of the problem:
Description: I have a Step Functions state machine that invokes a Lambda function. The Lambda function returns a JSON response body. However, when I execute the state machine, the response captured in the Step Functions output is not as expected.
Expected Behavior: I expect the Step Functions output to capture the entire response body returned by the Lambda function.
Java code:
public ResponseEntity<Object> fetchCertificateStatus() {
        String jsonData = "{\"name\": \"John\", \"age\": 30, \"city\": \"New York\"}";

        // Parse the JSON data to a Java object
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Person person = gson.fromJson(jsonData, Person.class);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(person);

    
    }

Step Function code:
{

  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "Lambda Invoke",
  "States": {
    "Lambda Invoke": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:72806977b",
      "ResultPath": "$.LambdaResponse",  // Store the entire Lambda response here
      "End": true
    }
  }
}

Current output:
{
  "LambdaResult": 200
}

current output**
Expected Result on Step function state:**
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "city": "New York"
}

**
Issue Details:**

The Step Functions output only captures a status code (e.g., 200) instead of the entire response body.

Attempts to use specific ResultPath values like LambdaResult and LambdaResponseBody didn't yield the expected results.

The Lambda function itself is correctly returning the JSON response body when tested independently through tools like Postman.


FYI: Lambda is deployed and running with java at runtime.
Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified that the Lambda function ARN in the state machine configuration is correct.

Ensured that the Lambda function returns the response body in the expected JSON format.

Checked CloudWatch logs for both the Lambda function and the Step Functions execution for any error messages.


Expecting : the full json response body in the output tab of state machine.

There is a Java based developer tutorial that shows you the correct way to read data. This example application analyzes and stores customer feedback cards. Specifically, it fulfills the need of a fictitious hotel in New York City. The hotel receives feedback from guests in various languages in the form of physical comment cards. That feedback is uploaded into the app through a web client. After an image of a comment card is uploaded.
This example app makes use of Lambda/Step functions. I recommend looking at the code in this example.
Create an application that analyzes customer feedback and synthesizes audio
One diff I see in the Lambda that moves JSON to next step:
public class AnalyzeSentimentHandler implements RequestHandler<Map<String, Object>, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    public JSONObject handleRequest(Map<String, Object> requestObject, Context context) {
        String sourceText = (String) requestObject.get("source_text");
        context.getLogger().log("Extracted text: " +sourceText);
        DetectSentimentService detectSentimentService = new DetectSentimentService();
        JSONObject jsonOb = detectSentimentService.detectSentiments(sourceText);
        context.getLogger().log("JSON: " + jsonOb.toJSONString());
        return jsonOb;
    }
}

I would recommend running this example and looking at all the code to see how it works.
